# String not being printed/initialized properly

Tags: c++, string

I've been working on a Hangman game in Cpp...
So I created a variable called `SoFar` which stores dashes in the starting, but is gradually uncovered.

```
for(i = 0; i <= TheWord.length(); i++)
            SoFar[i] = '-';
```

So, I (try to) initialize `SoFar` to contain dashes in the starting, and be the same length as `TheWord`

Later on, when I print SoFar, it's just empty!

```
cout << "\nSo far, the word is : " << SoFar << endl;
```

[image: Picture showing output]

Any and all advice is appreciated. Here is my full program, for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <cctype>

using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

    vector<string> words;
    words.push_back("SHAWARMA");
    words.push_back("PSUEDOCODE");
    words.push_back("BIRYANI");
    words.push_back("TROLLED");
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    string TheWord = words[(rand() % words.size()) + 1];
    string SoFar;        
    const int MAXTRIES = 8;
    string used = "";
    int tries, i;
    i = tries = 0;
    char guess;
        for(i = 0; i <= TheWord.length(); i++)
            SoFar[i] = '-';

    while(tries <= MAXTRIES && SoFar != TheWord)
    {
        /****************************************************************/
        /*                          I/0                                 */
        /****************************************************************/
        cout << "\nYou haz " << MAXTRIES - tries << " tries to go!\n" ;
        cout << "You've used the following letters : ";

        for(i = 0; i <= used.length(); i++)
            cout << used[i] << " : " ;

        cout << "\nSo far, the word is : " << SoFar << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter your guess : " ;
        cin >> guess;
        /****************************************************************/
        /*                          Processing input                    */
        /****************************************************************/
        if(used.find(guess) != string::npos)
            continue;
        guess = toupper(guess);
        if(TheWord.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            for(i = 0; i <= TheWord.length(); i++)
            {
                if(guess == TheWord[i])
                    SoFar[i] = guess;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nSorry, but the word doesn't have a letter like " << guess << " in it...\n";
            tries++;
        }   
                used += guess;

    }

    if(tries == MAXTRIES)
        cout << "\nYep, you've been hanged...\n";
    else if(SoFar == TheWord)
        cout << "\nYou got it! Congratulations...\n(Now Im gonna add some psuedorandomly generated words just for you <3 :P)";

    cout << "\nThe word was : " << TheWord;

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `SoFar` as:

```
string SoFar;
```

...then you try to write to it:

```
    for(i = 0; i <= TheWord.length(); i++)
        SoFar[i] = '-';
```

When you write to it, `SoFar` still has a length of 0, so every time you execute `SoFar[i] = '-';`, you get undefined behavior.

Try:

```
std::string SoFar(TheWord.length(), '-');
```

This defines `SoFar` already containing the right number of dashes.

Here's a quick demo:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){ 
    std::string TheWord{"TROLLED"};

    std::string SoFar(TheWord.length(), '-');

    std::cout << TheWord << "\n";
    std::cout << SoFar << "\n";
}
```

At least for me, this seems to produce the correct length of result:

```
TROLLED
-------
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to modify objects that don't exist:

```
string SoFar;        
const int MAXTRIES = 8;
string used = "";
int tries, i;
i = tries = 0;
char guess;
    for(i = 0; i <= TheWord.length(); i++)
        SoFar[i] = '-';
```

Since `SoFar` is empty, trying to modify `SoFar[i]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: Use the fill constructor, `string (size_t n, char c);`.

Answer (score 1):

you have specified that the soFar as string so try using double quotes for value

```
for(i = 0; i <= TheWord.length(); i++)
SoFar[i] = "-";
```